Help reading archaic phrasing in おみくじ
Despite being relatively confident with Japanese, I'm quite flabbergasted trying to translate the full text of a おみくじ.  For example, for this fortune here,

my questions include:

Near the top, what are those blocks of five kanji with the katakana in the middle?
What is 物事独りする?  Neither that nor 物事一人する appear in dictionaries.
Is 順うてすれば an archaic form of 従えば?
What is 心みじかける?
What does おそし mean? (Similar question for words here like たし, すし)
Is するも an archaic form of しても?
What is that long squiggle line in 失せ物ゆる----さがせ?

I know this is a large number of questions so I appreciate the help.  If there is a video/website/guide with some general tips for おみくじ reading, that would also be great.

This is a lot of different questions tied together, and might benefit from being separated out. For instance, the long squiggle line is the vertical repetition marker discussed previously in this question.


Those blocks of kanji are the おみくじ text writtne in 漢文. The ひらがな is its 書き[下]{くだ}し文 (transcription in Japanese). The Japanese text in the lower half is its translation (or interpretation? 翻訳というより解釈?) and explanation in Japanese.

物事独りする ⇒ [物事]{ものごと}を一人でする。 to do things on your own, in your own way.

人に[順]{したご}うてすれば ⇒ 人に[順]{したが}って（物事を）すれば。
If you do things with someone/others, following someone/others

心短ければ -- 心短し + ば ⇒ 気が[短]{みじか}ければ。気が短かったら。[短気]{たんき}ならば。 If you are short tempered.

おそし ⇒ 遅い。 (will arrive) late. will take time.

たし -- かないがたし ⇒ [叶]{かな}い[難]{がた}い。 difficult to come true.

すし -- 子に縁うすし ⇒ 子供に縁が[薄]{うす}い。 chance of (having) a child is small.

するも -- can be するけれども(although) or しても(even if).

[失]{う}せ物はゆるゆるさがせ ⇒ 無くしたもの（探し物）は、ゆっくり探せ。


